# Fetching nested JSON data using key,value

Tags: json, angular

Below is my method from .ts file. With this method the keys are displayed but I am unable to fetch the nested JSON data.

```
generateArr(obj) {
return Object.keys(obj).map((key) => {
  console.log(key, obj[key]);
  return {key: key, value: obj[key]};
 });
}
```

Below is my HTML code.

```
<li *ngFor="let ob of books">
  <p *ngFor="let objArrEle of generateArr(ob);let i=index"> 
    {{objArrEle.key}}: {{objArrEle.value}} 
  </p>
</li>
```

Please tell me the solution.

Comment: You can't have spaces like "objArrEle .key". This should be objArrEle.key

Comment: a typing mistake

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xqvyaf?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Non nested data from json file is fetched but not the nested one

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to fetch the nested JSON using interpolation `{{}}` in HTML, it will display`[Object object]`. If you want to display the nested data also, you may want to recursively call `generateArr(obj)` for each nested property. If you are using Angular 7, have a look at [KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe).

Created a solution for you using stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nestedjson. you can nest JSON for any level. I'm not so good with CSS, please fell free to change that.